# Distorting a 2D object to give the appearance of 3D Space

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to recreate the following image from [Yoshua Bengio's slides](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/talks/UCL-masterclass3-23oct2013.pdf):
[image: Manifold interpretation of denoising autoencoders]

So far, I've made the flat rectangle object, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to "distort it" in Inkscape. The path tool lets me do this for individual paths drawn with the pen tool, but I can't figure out how to do it for the entire object.
[image: Flat Rectangle]

Comment: looking at the original image, it seems it was done manually (i.e. it's a 2D drawing with no 3D transformations, and the objects were deformed individually)

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I wanted to make a cleaner version of it.

Comment: I've no time now to write a decent answer, but you can **combine** your objects in a path and add an **effect**: [Envelope deformation](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-EnvelopeDeformation.html). It should help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Envelope deformation](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-EnvelopeDeformation.html) effect, but you need to [convert to path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html) each object, because the *Envelope deformation* tools works only on paths or group of paths.

In the following example I've converted to path rectangles, circles and text just by grouping all the objects and using *Path...Object to path*. With the group *selected*, you need to show the **Path effects** dialog (*Path...Path effects* or *Ctrl+Shift+7*):

[image: the dialog]

Clicking the "+" button, you can add the *Envelope deformation* effect:

[image: add path effect]

Now you need to perform some manual work. The effect allows to apply a deformation to each side of your object.

You can start with the top side, by clicking the related *Edit on-canvas* icon:

[image: edit on-canvas]

Dragging the nodes you can see immediately the deformation, e.g.:

[image: deformation]

And so on:

[image: similar but not perfect]

With a little tweaking you can achieve a result similar to the desired one.